# RESTful from Google Apps Script

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I invoke a RESTful webserice via a method GET url with paramters from google apps script successfully using the following:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
```

But when I switch the method to use POST, the result returned tells that no parameter was sent:

```
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

I also tried to use Google Chrome's (Advanced) Rest Client, and the payload parameters are not sent there as well.

What am I missing?

Below is the Google Chrome's (Advanced) Rest Client interface.

[image]

Comment: What is the code for the `options` parameter?

Comment: var data = {"x1": "1", "x2": "2"};
    data = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {method : "post", payload : data};

Comment: In addition to this, I tested this webservice using a plain Java App, and a Java client with Apache HttpClient using method POST, they didn't work either.

Comment: Do you think the issue is Google, or the URL being called?  Is the URL an API?

Comment: The URL is an API. It's a black box for me. Even with the Chrome REST Client, the API accepts Query Parameters, but ignores Payload Parameters.

Comment: I updated the question with a snapshot of REST Client.

Comment: The Advanced Rest Client is a way to test REST requests.  If the REST request is not configured correctly, or it's not configured correctly for whatever is on the receiving end, then it won't work.  How the REST request is configured may have nothing to do with the `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)` method.  By process of elimination, if the REST request worked with Google Chrome's (Advanced) Rest Client, but didn't work with `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`, then I'd think that the service wasn't working or there was a bug.

Answer (score 2):

You mention in your comments that you are converting the payload you send to JSON.

First, are you certain the remote service is expecting a JSON payload, rather than form encoded data?

If the service expects form encoded data, don't JSON.stringify your payload:

```
var data = {"x1": "1", "x2": "2"}; 
var options = {method : "post", payload : data};
```

If the service does expect a JSON payload, you need to set the content type:

```
var data = {"x1": "1", "x2": "2"}; 
data = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {method : "post", payload : data, contentType:"application/json"};
```

Otherwise the default content type of  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is used.

See the description on "contentType" under "Advanced Parameters": https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app

Comment: Well, after investigation, I think the API accepts only Query String Parameters. Thank you for your response though!